# python2.7 - taking a value from a dictionary, where the key is a variable

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I'm trying to load a specific key from a dictionary, with keys like "character 1", "translation 1", etc. (I'm working a a flashcard program for my chinese studies). First, I load the dictionary flawlessly from a .txt file with

```
f = codecs.open(('%s.txt' % list_name),'r','utf-8')
quiz_list = eval(f.read())
```

Then, I want the program to print the list in order, so that I would get something along the lines of

```
"1. ('character 1' value)    ('pinyin 1' value)    ('translation 1' value)"
```

The program registers how many entries the list has and calculates the amount of chinese words it has to show (with each word having its own character, transcription and translation and entry number). Now, I want to load the first chinese word from the list, with the 3 keys "character 1", "pinyin 1" and "translation 1".

The tried-and-tested way of retrieving values from a dictionary is through my_dictionary[key]. However, if I were to insert the name of a variable in the part between brackets, python would read the name of this variable as the name of a key, and not use the *value* of the variable. Is there a way of doing the latter the right way? I have, for example, tried the following (obviously to no avail) to load key "character 1" from the list:

```
i = 1
character_to_load = "character %s" % str(i)
print quiz_list[character_to_load]
```

Any hints are extremely appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the output of `print str(type(quiz_list)), quiz_list` ?

Comment: @pajton

<type 'dict'> {'translation 1': 'dilligent', 'pinyin 1': 'ren4wei2', 'character 1': '\xe8\xaa\x8d\xe7\x88\xb2'}

Comment: Can you post the error you get? I can't replicate the problem...

Comment: BTW you don't need to convert `i` to a string and then use `%s` as a formatting character; you can just do `"character %i" % 5`.

Comment: Also the recommended method for string formatting is now `"character {:d}".format(5)`. Which doesn't use the icky `%` operator. And lets you do nice things like `"character {d[0]}".format(d=[5])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you question right, I believe you might have some bug in the code, as this works fine:

```
>>> d =  {'translation 1': 'dilligent', 'pinyin 1': 'ren4wei2', 'character 1': '\xe8\xaa\x8d\xe7\x88\xb2'}
>>> key = "translation %s" % 1
>>> d[key]
'dilligent'
```

Does it help?

Comment: I bow my head in shame, it turned out I did not have the for-loop that printed every word entry in the proper order properly set up, so nothing was printed. I was already confused I did not actually get any error messages, so this explains it. Everything works flawlessly now. Thanks alot for your time!

Comment: @user1058744 no worries... Slips happened now and then even to Alan Turing himself! ;)

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution to this problem, instead of flattening the data structure into a dictionary keyed by strings, is to use a better data structure. For instance, if you have a lot of keys that look like `"translation n"` for numbers `n`, you'd be better off making `translation` a dictionary keyed by numbers.  You might even want to make the lookup go the other way: you could have a `Word` object (or whatever) which has properties `translation`, `pinyin` and `character`, and then have a list of `Word`s.

You should build this data structure properly, instead of `eval`ing a file. That's basically never a good idea, because it's horribly fragile: you're forcing the text file to be pure Python, but not writing it as a module. Instead, you should iterate over the lines in the file and build up the data structure as you go.

If you tell me the current structure of your file I can give you an example as to how to parse it properly.

Comment: I solved the problem, apparently I had a minor error in the for-loop for printing every single word entry in the correct order. But thanks alot for the recommendation, I see what you're getting at. I'll be rebuilding this thing into a more sensible structure.